# C++ multiple access specifiers and order of initialization

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, initialization-order

We know that in the following code

```
class Foo1 {
private:
    int i;
    bool b;
public:
    Foo1() : i(7), b(false) {} 
};
```

"i" is going to be init before "b". If I try to init "b" before "i", I'll get a warning.

what about this case:

```
class Foo2 {
private:
    int i;
private:
    bool b;
public:
    // what happens if b is first because compiler reordered?
    Foo2() : b(false),  i(7) {} 
};
```

?

We know that the compiler is free to order "i" and "b" since they are in separate access specifiers.

So what is the order of initialization in this case?

anything guaranteed like in the previous simple case?

Comment: The required effect of both constructor initialisation lists is an object with the member `i` having value of `7` and `b` a value of `false`.   That doesn't change if the compiler reorders things.

Comment: Class members are initialized/constructed in order of declaration. Whether each individual class member is public, private, or protected, is irrelevant.

Comment: When you mention the ordering of `i` and `b` being free for the compiler to decide, perhaps you are talking about the way how access specifiers [may affect the class layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access): _the addresses of non-static data members are only guaranteed to increase in order of declaration for the members with the same access_. So, for example, the compiler may place all `private` members before all `public` members. But this has nothing to do with the order of member initialization: those are initialized in order of declaration, regardless of memory layout.

Comment: thanks @heap underrun  this is exactly what I wanted to know. is there any correlation between layout and init. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of initialization is guaranteed; `i` is always initialized before `b`. Non-static data members are initialized in the order of their declaration in the class definition, regardless of their access specifiers.

[[class.base.init]/13.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#13.3)

> Then, non-static data members are initialized in the order they were declared in the class definition (again regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).